# What is the area leftover from an inscribed circle called

Tags: geometry, terminology

What are the little triangle things called (displayed as red in the picture)?
If the ones on the corners and the ones on the sides are different, then I would like to know those names too.

[image: picture here]

Comment: "excluded portion"?

Answer (score 3):

There's no widely adopted name for these portions of the rectangle.
The situation depicted on your drawing does not seem so common
for these figures (or this figure) to deserve a special name.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any established name for such geometric figures.

I take the liberty to suggest one:

*Hazelnut Cookie Leftovers*

[image]

(from http://plummytales.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I would call them "Circle complements", taking the circle to be a set, and it's "negation" to be its complement. I would think anyone listening with some background in Set Theory would get the name.